# How to check if a topic is available or not using Apache-Camel

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to write a condition where before implementing the Kafka-Camel route, I check if there is the destination topic is available or not. If the topic is missing, the routing doesn't happen.

The reason I am doing this is, when there is no topic and the routing is invoked, the NetworkClient creates the topic by sending out a warning like below.

2022-06-15 14:36:38 WARN  [or.ap.ka.cl.NetworkClient] (kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-8) [Producer clientId=producer-8] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 3 : {my-topic=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}

I want to avoid the automatic creation of topic. If there is no topic, I want to skip the routing.

Comment: its always better to turn off automatic topic creation option in cluster if not required, let the producer fail if topic is not available, which is a requisite for your app.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you can since Camel is more for integration of systems rather than direct communication to one system.

Similarly, Kafka Connect itself requires a working Kafka cluster, and assumes destination topics are already available, but latest releases of Kafka (as of 2.6) do provide the option to auto-create source connector topics. You can set `topic.creation.enable=false` to disable this, but then you'll be flooded with errors saying `UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION`. To ignore those, you can try setting `errors.tolerance`, but then you'd potentially be ignoring other exceptions